# Android MediaPlayer unable to play media file from local storage

Tags: android, video, media-player

I am trying to make a media player play a media file stored in the local/external storage.

The media file is downloaded using a separate activity and stored in the local/external storage.See below for the sample code for storing.

```
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("myfile.mp4" , Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    fos.write(byteArrayBuf.toByteArray());
    fos.close();
```

For playing the same file, I use.

```
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File( URI.create("file:///data/data/com.mypackage/files/myfile.mp4")),ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(parcel.getFileDescriptor());
    mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mHolder);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    /** On Prepared Implementation **/
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

However, the media player refuses to play the file and always fails with an error(1, ). I am really at my wits end to make this media player running as I seem to have done everything which is inline with the code samples to make it read a file from local/external storage.

Note: when i substitute a local file with a file from the res/raw folder this seems to play fine. is this specifically related to the file not being readable by the application or the media player. Help would be really appreciated to make this piece work.

## **Update 1**

@Chris : 
I have temporarily made the file WORLD_WRITEABLE and once I get the media player to work would in fact write files as WORLD_READABLE.
Hard-coding the paths is deliberate as of now as I just want to initially ensure that the file gets read without any ambiguity. In fact I have checked that the file does exist by going through adb shell and DDMS.Once i get the file read, in fact I will probably use something more sensible like getFilesDir(). Logcat output as below.

```
    surfaceCreated
    I/AwesomePlayer(   34): reset
    I/AwesomePlayer(   34): cancel player events
    I/AwesomePlayer(   34): cancel player events
    I/SampleTable(   34): There are reordered frames present.
    D/MyPlayerActivity(  460): surfaceChanged
    I/ActivityManager(   82): Displayed com.mypackage/.MyPlayerActivity: +1s997ms
    D/MyPlayerActivity(  460): Video Prepared
    D/AudioSink(   34): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
    E/MediaPlayer(  460): error (1, -2147483648)
    E/MediaPlayer(  460): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Comment: You should not be hard-coding a path under /data but instead determining it dynamically at runtime.  Also, do you really want to make the file writeable by other apps?  Posting logcat would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Stratton commented, don't hard-code paths to either the internal or external storage. They may work on some systems but are not guaranteed for every system.

Use `getFilesDir()` to find the path of the directory. From the docs...

> public File getFilesDir ()
>
> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.
>
> Returns the path of the directory holding application files.

You can call `getAbsolutePath()` on the returned `File` and append `/myfile.mp4` to it and use that to `setDataSource(...)` on the `Mediaplayer`.